# Help solving $5^{-4} \left(\frac{2x+5}{8}\right)^2 = 49$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve a simple formula but I get lost in the orders of operation.

The formula is:

$5^{ -4}{ \left( \frac { 2x+5 }{ 8 }  \right)  }^{ 2 } =49$

The easy parts:

$5^{-4} = 0.0016$

$\sqrt { 49 }  = 7$

So that gives me:

$-0.0016(2x+5/8) = 7$

Am I now allowed to to divide both sides of the equal sign with X to get:

$-0.0016(2+5/8) = 7/x$

?

And if that is correct, then the order of operation is as follows, right?

$-0.0016((2/8)+5) = 7/x$

Am I messing it up completely? :)

Comment: Something that will really help the question, for readability, is to format it properly, here is a nice page that gives you a quick tutorial on how to do so, for future questions! http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: As to the question, to start with, where is the negative coming from when you calculate $5^{-4}$? Check your work on a calculator for these simple things, until you get used to them, but $5^{-4} = 0.0016$, not $-0.0016$. You'll also need to remember that when you take the square root of both sides of your equation $0.0016(2x + \frac{5}{8})^2 = 49$, you need to take the square root of everything on the left side: $\sqrt{0.0016(2x + \frac{5}{8})^2} = \sqrt{49}$. What is $\sqrt{0.0016(2x+\frac{5}{8})^2}$?

Comment: Battani did a very fine job reformatting the question. so the 2x+8 is completely above the divider, and 8 is below of it. But without any additional braces. So I guess that is my main confusion. How does that follow the rules of order of operations? Will it become the 2x/8 + 5? Or is it perfectly correct in mathematics and will it in fact be (2x+5)/8 ?

Comment: @gesa ah right thanks a lot for that pointer! if you could be kind enough to give away the one remainder of my question in the comment above?

Comment: Oops, my mistake, so we have $\sqrt{0.0016(\frac{2x+5}{8})^2} =\sqrt{49} $. Now, we can rewrite this as: $\sqrt{0.0016} \cdot (\frac{2x + 5}{8}) = 7$, which I think is what you were trying to get to before. Now, we have something in parenthesis multiplied by $\sqrt{0.0016}$ on the left: essentially, we have $\sqrt{0.0016}\cdot (something)$. How do we get rid of the $\sqrt{0.0016}$ from the left hand side?

Comment: We can't make $\frac{2x + 5}{8} = \frac{2x}{8} + 5$, that was my mistake, I read the original question wrong. $\frac{2x + 5}{8} = \frac{2x}{8} + \frac{5}{8}$, since we can split up addition in the numerator of a fraction. The easiest way to deal with the expression in parenthesis is to leave it as is, until we get rid of the $\sqrt{0.0016}$.

Comment: So it's not mandatory to use braces when writing {{2x + 5}/8}? It's mathematically correct to write it without? Then I think I have my answer (in that case x = 697.5 or -702.5). (sorry still having a hard time to write properly formatted equations...)

Comment: Your answers are correct. And yes, it is mathematically correct to write it without braces. You need to be careful, because it's not correct to write $\frac{2x+5}{8}^2$ instead of $)\frac{2x+5}{8})^2$, in that situation you need the braces to signify that you are raising the whole expression in braces to the power of $2$. But, after you get rid of the exponent, in this case, it's ok.

Comment: @gesa, thank you for your help. If you care to drop it as answer I'll accept it. Thanks for the educating parts, been a while for me I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, walking through this step-by-step, in case someone finds this question in the future and needs a more detailed answer, we have

$$5^{-4}\left(\frac{2x+5}{8}\right)^2 = 49.$$

Now, our order of operations tells us to take care of "parenthesis" first. However the expression inside the parenthesis is about as simple as it can get, so we'll leave that alone, for now, and instead take of the exponents. As you calculated, $5^{-4} = 0.0016$, so we have

$$0.0016\left(\frac{2x +5}{8}\right)^2 = 49.$$

We still have an exponent that we would like to get rid of. We can do so by taking the square root of both side, as you did in your attempt, but making sure to square root everything on both sides. This gives us:

$$\sqrt{0.0016 \left(\frac{2x+5}{8}\right)^2} = \sqrt{49}$$
$$\sqrt{0.0016}\left(\frac{2x + 5}{8}\right) = \sqrt{49}.$$

Now, we'll divide each side of our equation by $\sqrt{0.0016}$, and we have

$$\frac{2x + 5}{8} = \frac{\sqrt{49}}{\sqrt{0.0016}} = \sqrt{\frac{49}{0.0016}},$$

The right hand side of this equation is either $175$, or $-175$. So, we have

$$\frac{2x+5}{8} = 175 \ \ \ \text{ or } \ \ \ \frac{2x+5}{8} = -175,$$

and these expressions give us

$$2x + 5 = 1400 \ \ \ \text{ or } \ \ \ 2x + 5 = -1400$$

$$2x = 1395 \ \ \ \text{ or } \ \ \ 2x = -1405$$

$$x =697.5 \ \ \ \text{ or } \ \ \ x = -702.5$$

Comment: There is a typo: $1400-5\neq 1305$.

Comment: Fixed, thank you @Ennar

Answer (score 1):

Just a small recommendation, when you condense some constants to decimal form you potentially lose a lot of information within those variables, for example $\frac 17 \neq 0.1428$, but it's convenient to think of it as such, in reality the decimal goes on infinitely.

As for your question:
$$5^{-4}\left(\frac{2x+5}{8}\right)^2=5^{-4}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^2(2x+5)^2 =5^{-4}2^{-6}(2x+5)^2 = 49$$
$$\implies (2x+5)^2 = 49\cdot 5^{4}\cdot 2^{6} = 2^6\cdot 5^4\cdot 7^2$$
$$\implies 2x+5= \pm\ 2^3\cdot5^2\cdot 7 = \pm\ 1400$$
$$\implies 2x = -5 \pm 1400\implies x = 700-\frac52,\ -700-\frac 52$$
$$\implies x = 697.5, -702.5$$

In general, you want to 'peel back the layers' of operations which surround $x$, and the way you do that is by observing the opposite mathematical operation which will undo that 'layer'. Multiplying by $5^4\cdot 2^6$ for example to remove constants, and taking a square root to remove the square.

Answer (score -1):

I would have opted for immediately taking the square root of both sides, if just to simplify the numbers!  $\sqrt{5^{-4}\left(\frac{2x+ 5}{8}\right)^2}= \sqrt{49}$ or $5^{-2}\left(\frac{2x+ 5}{8}\right)= 7$.  Multiplying on both sides by $5^2= 25$, $\frac{2x+ 5}{8}= 175$.  Multiply on both sides by 8, $2x+ 5= 1400$.  I let you do the rest!

Comment: You lost one solution by taking roots; $\sqrt{5^{-4}\left(\frac{2x+5}{8}\right)^2}=\pm \sqrt{49}$.